# how to set the width of a float button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

this button is affecting everything that is in the same line with it, how do i make it fixed without having it affect the things on the same line with it. the fields are affected by the save button. if the save button is is the same line as the form field, it affects the form field

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form asp-action="Create">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="EmployeeCode" value="@EmpCode" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="IndustryId" class="control-label"></label>
                    <select asp-for="IndustryId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.IndustryId"></select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="SubIndustryId" class="control-label"></label>
                    <select asp-for="SubIndustryId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.SubIndustryId">
                        <option selected> - None - </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="YearsExp" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="YearsExp" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="YearsExp" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Proficiency" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Proficiency" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Proficiency" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="BusinessArea" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="BusinessArea" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="BusinessArea" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Feature" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Feature" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Feature" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="fixed-bottom">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="text-right" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-primary" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fixed-bottom">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="text-right" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
              <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Send the screen short off your issue

Comment: You should add a [mcve]

Comment: added the code for the form, i am using ASP.NET core 2

Answer (score 0):

I've created a preview here: https://www.bootply.com/eItE7SJoQb

Maybe if you were to place the 'things on the same line' that you don't want it to affect..?

Comment: i added the code for the form, i am using ASP.NET core 2